# points.dist = function () { ^ ReferenceError: points is not defined

Tags: javascript, function

This function was copied from "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" but for some reason it doesn't work...   `**points.dist = function () {     ^  ReferenceError: points is not defined**`
Im new at this, and im not sure if an doing it right

```js
points.dist = function() {
    var p1 = this[0];
    var p2 = this[1];
    var a = p2.x-p1.x;
    var b = p2.y-p1.y;
    return Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);
};

console.log(points.dist())
```

Comment: It's telling you that `points` is not defined. You haven't shown anything in the code that defines it, so it seems like the error is correct. Maybe you are missing some code from earlier in the book where `points` is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var points = [
    {x:0, y:0},
    {x:1, y:1}
];

points.dist = function() {
    var p1 = this[0];
    var p2 = this[1];
    var a = p2.x-p1.x;
    var b = p2.y-p1.y;
    return Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);
};

console.log(points.dist()); // => 1.414 distance between two points
```

It calculates the distance between two points and you're here defining your own method `dist` to `points` Array object. It's invoking first and second element using `this[0]` and `this[1]` object and stores it in `p1` and `p2` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

you should at least define points object with default values

```
// Arrays and objects can hold other arrays and objects:
var points = [ // An array with 2 elements.
 {x:0, y:0}, // Each element is an object.
 {x:1, y:1}
];
```